# Android NDK: Failed to call C++ constructor

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to port a C++ desktop program to Android using NDK. When Debugging I found that the constructor of class Constants is not called when initializing class Windows, leaving width_ and height_ to 0, and the call trace is weird.
[image]

Debug line:
https://github.com/speedyHKjournalist/OpenMapleClient/blob/main/app/src/main/cpp/src/IO/Window.cpp#L34

From trace it seems that Error Game::init(android_app *pApp) is not called ?
Trace:

```
(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1, name = 'ri0.glfwexample', stop reason = step over
  * frame #0: 0x0000007535ddfd70 libglfw-example.so`ms::Window::Window(this=0x00000075360ba990) at Window.cpp:34:21
    frame #1: 0x0000007535b5fad8 libglfw-example.so`::__cxx_global_var_init.10() at Singleton.h:33:17
    frame #2: 0x000000766d648bb8 linker64`__dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv + 632
    frame #3: 0x000000766d63301c linker64`__dl__Z9do_dlopenPKciPK17android_dlextinfoPKv + 2288
    frame #4: 0x000000766d62e100 linker64`__dl___loader_android_dlopen_ext + 88
    frame #5: 0x00000076561bc110 libdl.so`android_dlopen_ext + 24
    frame #6: 0x000000766b9243dc libnativeloader.so`android::NativeLoaderNamespace::Load(char const*) const + 200
    frame #7: 0x000000766b914e74 libnativeloader.so`OpenNativeLibraryInNamespace + 72
    frame #8: 0x000000766b91459c libnativeloader.so`OpenNativeLibrary + 140
    frame #9: 0x000000765191ae00 libandroid_runtime.so`android::loadNativeCode_native(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jstring*, _jstring*, _jobject*, _jstring*, _jstring*, _jstring*, int, _jobject*, _jbyteArray*, _jobject*, _jstring*) + 308
    frame #10: 0x00000000721bec14 boot-framework.oat`art_jni_trampoline + 308
    frame #11: 0x00000075c0e18968 libart.so`art_quick_invoke_stub + 552
    frame #12: 0x00000075c0e85ff4 libart.so`art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*) + 196
    frame #13: 0x00000075c0fea3ec libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 408
    frame #14: 0x00000075c0fe618c libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 708
    frame #15: 0x00000075c0e2cd38 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 23432
    frame #16: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #17: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #18: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #19: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #20: 0x00000075c0fe6170 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 680
    frame #21: 0x00000075c0e2dc40 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 27280
    frame #22: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #23: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #24: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #25: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #26: 0x00000075c0fe4f64 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 796
    frame #27: 0x00000075c0e2dc70 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 27328
    frame #28: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #29: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #30: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #31: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #32: 0x00000075c0fe4f64 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 796
    frame #33: 0x00000075c0e2dc70 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 27328
    frame #34: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #35: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #36: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #37: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #38: 0x00000075c0fe5964 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 1704
    frame #39: 0x00000075c0e54774 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 47036
    frame #40: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #41: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #42: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #43: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #44: 0x00000075c0fe5964 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 1704
    frame #45: 0x00000075c0e52350 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 37784
    frame #46: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #47: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #48: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #49: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #50: 0x00000075c0fe4f64 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 796
    frame #51: 0x00000075c0e2dc70 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 27328
    frame #52: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #53: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #54: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #55: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #56: 0x00000075c0fe4f64 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 796
    frame #57: 0x00000075c0e2dc70 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 27328
    frame #58: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #59: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #60: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #61: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #62: 0x00000075c0fe4f64 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 796
    frame #63: 0x00000075c0e2dc70 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 27328
    frame #64: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #65: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #66: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #67: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #68: 0x00000075c0fe4f64 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 796
    frame #69: 0x00000075c0e2dc70 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 27328
    frame #70: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #71: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #72: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #73: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #74: 0x00000075c0fe4f64 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 796
    frame #75: 0x00000075c0e2dc70 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 27328
    frame #76: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #77: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #78: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #79: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #80: 0x00000075c0fe4f64 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 796
    frame #81: 0x00000075c0e2dc70 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 27328
    frame #82: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #83: 0x00000075c0fe4934 libart.so`art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitch(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool) + 324
    frame #84: 0x00000075c0fdccd4 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 224
    frame #85: 0x00000075c0fe44a8 libart.so`art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*) + 212
    frame #86: 0x00000075c0fe4f64 libart.so`bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*) + 796
    frame #87: 0x00000075c0e2ce70 libart.so`void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*) + 23744
    frame #88: 0x00000075c0e24bdc libart.so`ExecuteSwitchImplAsm + 12
    frame #89: 0x00000075c136b554 libart.so`MterpInvokeStatic + 2552
    frame #90: 0x00000075c0e03998 libart.so`mterp_op_invoke_static + 24
    frame #91: 0x00000075c0fdcd30 libart.so`art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) + 316
    frame #92: 0x00000075c134e560 libart.so`artQuickToInterpreterBridge + 784
    frame #93: 0x00000075c0e2237c libart.so`art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge + 92
    frame #94: 0x00000075c0e22590 libart.so
```

Comment: The way that `Singleton` is implemented it provides no guarantee whatsoever in which order the singletons will be initialized or in which order they are initialized relative to other global variables, causing undefined behavior. The pattern is incorrect. Singletons shouldn't be `static` member variables, especially not in templates. Instead they should be function-scope `static` variables. See core guidelines https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ri-singleton and https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i2-avoid-non-const-global-variables.

Comment: Also terms to search for in that context: "static initialization order fiasco", "unordered dynamic initialization" and "Meyers' singleton"

Comment: Please don't post images of text (code, error messages or whatever). Post *plain text* instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user17732522 correctly pointed out you have no guarantees on the initialization order.

So I'd change Singleton class as follows:

```
template<class T>
class Singleton {
public:
    virtual ~Singleton() = default;

    static T &get() { 
        static T instance_;
        return instance_;
    }

private:
    T &operator=(const T &) = delete;
};

// No need for the code above
// template<class T>
// T Singleton<T>::instance_;
```